# Где здесь ошибка?с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
string& refToeElement(vector<string>& inventory, int i);
int main()
{
    vector<string>inventory;
    inventory.push_back("sword");
    inventory.push_back("armor");
    inventory.push_back("shield");
    cout << "Sending the returned reference to cout:\n";
    cout << refToeElement(inventory, 0) << "\n\n";
    cout << "Assigning the returned reference to another reference.\n";
    string& rStr = refToeElement(inventory, 1);
    cout << "Sending the new reference to cout:\n";
    cout << rStr << "\n\n";
    cout << "Assigning the returned reference to a string object.\n";
    string str = refToeElement(inventory, 2);
    cout << "Sending the new string object to cout:\n";
    cout << str << "\n\n";
    cout << "Altering an object through a returned reference.\n ";
    rStr = "Healing Potion";
    cout << "Sending the altered object to cout:\n";
    cout << inventory[1] << endl;
    return 0;
}

string& refToElement(vector<string>& vec, int i)
{
    return vec[i];
}
```

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, так как ответ на него вряд ли может быть полезен кому-либо помимо автора вопроса.

Answer (score 2):

Объявление и определение с разными именами...

```
string& refToeElement(vector<string>& inventory, int i);
string& refToElement(vector<string>& vec, int i)
```

Вот линковщик и не понимает, где ему брать `refToeElement`.